# IDLE crash when opening on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, crash, python-idle

I recently attempted to install python 3.2 along with IDLE 3 on my macbook pro. I successfully installed python 3.2 (as in, I can run it from the terminal), but when I attempted to install IDLE 3.2 I must have done something wrong because now both IDLE 2.7 and IDLE 3.2 crash immediately upon opening with the message "Python quit unexpectedly", no matter whether I open it through the terminal or through finder. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have installed the correct ActiveTCL package (and reinstalled) and still nothing. I have attempted to reinstall python 3.2 and IDLE 3 but I am not sure whether I did it correctly. Through a good amount of googling I found some people say that it was most likely a path issue but all of the solutions I found were using Windows so I am not sure how to apply that to my mac.

Comment: Try `import idlelib.idle` at the Python prompt, or `python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/idlelib/idle.py` at the Bash prompt.

Comment: "import idlelib.idle" caused the same crash as before and the other command said there was no such file or directory. So i copied the "3.2" folder from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions to the /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions folder and then re-entered the command. This is what I got: "Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **", file=sys._stderr_)  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You may not have the right version of TKinter installed. Try looking at [this](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/).

Comment: I have 8.5.11 installed. That is the correct one, right?

Comment: Never modify or delete files in `/System/Library`, which is part of OS X and managed by Apple.  There are no Python 3 releated files in `/System/Library` since Apple has yet to release a version of Python 3 in OS X.  If you installed Python 3.2 using a python.org installer, its files will be in `/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: I did not delete or replace anything in /System/Library and i know the folder is in /Library/Frameworks. That is pretty irrelevant to what I was asking but a still a good point i suppose.

Comment: Yes, but you said you copied the 3.2 folder to /System/Library.  That in itself is not a problem since there is no 3.2 folder in /System/Library.  But if someone followed that pattern and copied, say, a 2.7 folder from /Library to /System/Library, that would wipe out the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7 in 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming or removing the directory `~/.idlerc` which is about the only thing used by Python that would in common to IDLE for 2.7 and 3.2.  If that doesn't help, state exactly which Python 3 you installed, what version of OS X, and show the stack traces from the termination report.

UPDATE: Based on the crash report you've supplied, it appears that Tk is crashing during its initialization of menu items:

```
...
4   Tcl                             0x00000001013dfa61 Tcl_Panic + 162
5   Tk                              0x000000010151c523 TkpGetColor + 383
6   Tk                              0x0000000101529a25 TkpMenuInit + 156
7   Tk                              0x00000001014ac254 TkMenuInit + 88
8   Tk                              0x000000010152c687 -[TKApplication(TKMenus) _setupMenus] + 53
...
```

I have not seen any reports of a similar problems when IDLE is used with A/S Tcl/Tk 8.5 on 10.7.3 and I haven't been able to reproduce it myself on 10.7.3.  However, the Cocoa Tcl/Tk 8.5 is not the most robust framework out there and it may be susceptible to problems when using languages or input methods other than `US` or `US Extended`.  Another possibility (more likely) is if you are using some third-party menu enhancement application or preference panel (to add colors to menus perhaps).  If those suggestions don't help you to isolate the problem, I suggest you ask on the Tcl Mac mailing list (`tcl-mac@lists.sourceforge.net`, archived at http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.tcl.mac).

Comment: removing `~/.idlerc` will not mess anything up?

Comment: ~/.idlerc contains a few files where IDLE stores changed preferences, the names of recently edited files, and the like.  It is recreated as needed if not present.

Comment: I removed all programs that I thought may be "third-party menu enhancement application or preference panel" but I still cannot get it to work. If I reinstall Lion will that fix the problem?

Comment: It's impossible to say if reinstalling Lion will help.  It might.  But before that rather drastic step, note that ActiveState has recently released Tcl/Tk 8.5.11.1 with updates for various bugs.  If you haven't already installed that version, it would be worth trying that before anything else.  http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

Comment: I actually installed that earlier but IDLE is still crashing. If i reinstall and then load a backup through Time Machine will the python system files be reinstalled from the disk or from the backup? I suppose that is an option if I need it to be.

Comment: Python 3 is not shipped by Apple in OS X 10.7 so you don't need to reinstall Lion to reinstall that version of Python; just use the appropriate Python installer.  But, again, the crash report you linked to shows Tcl/Tk crashing, not Python.  Focus on things that might affect it, particularly in the area of menus: if not add-ons, then system preferences like language (try US English), fonts, input methods. And ask on the Tcl Mac mailing list.  Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to reinstall the original Tcl/Tk that comes with OSX? It seems like that may have broken from something I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Mac OS X Lion, it sounds like you are being bitten by the saved-state crash.  You need to delete the saved state to make the crash go away:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/17/delete-specific-application-saved-states-from-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-resume/

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20083707-263/managing-mac-os-x-lions-application-resume-feature/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didnt work for me. It still crashes.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. IDLE v3.2.3 python v3.2.3 and tk v8.5. However, great link for the saved-state (new to lion here) and I was happy about chflags nohidden ~/Library

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I run OSX 10.8.5, Python 3.3.3 and IDLE 3.3.3 and reinstalling Python haven't been a solution.
I solved any problem removing the `~/.idlerc` directory. My problem showed for the first time when I tried to change some Preferences (IDLE->Preferences->General->Startup Preferences->At Startup Open Edit Window), so I suppose that's why resetting my Preferences deleting `~/.idlerc`  folder have been the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where IDLE would crash after I opened it on my MAC
I ended up updating my computer to OS Yosemite. 
and the most updated version of python but it still would shut
  the reason it started was because I tried to change the preferences for certain keys.
Resetting the preferences fixed it! 
I typed mc ~/.idlerc idlerc2
 :)

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] I had the same problem here using:
Yosemite 10.10.2
python 3.4.2

The issue was solved downloading and installing the ActiveTcl 8.5.17.0  version from  http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

Best Regards,

Tchê