# IDLE crash on open Mac

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, python-idle

I'm on Lion 10.7. I open IDLE and it will bounce for a few seconds in the dock then go away. I can't run any modules and have tried reinstalling it as well as installing Python 2.7 over Python 3. I've also tried installing the latest ActiveTcl.

Here is the console log: http://pastebin.com/yHNkRqYj

Comment: Could this be your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384021/idle-and-idle-3-crash-on-opening-mac-osx

Comment: Kind of. Mine shows no error though. It shows up on the dock for a second then disappears. It worked fine for 3 weeks. The only thing I did before closing IDLE the last time it worked was use Chrome, Microsoft Word, and IDLE itself. I quit IDLE, closed my computer, then when I tried to open IDLE the next time, nothing happened. I have followed all kinds of advice but nothing seems to be working.