# IDLE crashes on my Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-idle

I've never used Python before and wanted to get started. I am running Mac OSX 10.5.8 and everytime I open IDLE I get the following error message:

```
The application IDLE quit unexpectedly
```

I just downloaded Python 2.7 because I heard that it had the most library support and I was very excited about the C/C++ Python interfacing capabilities. I did see other users on this site having similar problems but I still did not figure my issue out.

Any ideas on how I can get IDLE to run on my Mac?

Comment: I have a feeling that we're going to need some more information. What is your processor type (x32, x64, etc). What is the exact link from which you downloaded python and idle?

Comment: Also, You should be aware that OS X comes with a builtin version of python (2.7 for 10.5 I think).

Comment: I am running x64, and I now see my problem, as I downloaded python for 10.6

Comment: Try launching IDLE from a Terminal shell command line and report what errors, if any, are displayed:  `/usr/local/bin/idle2.7`

Comment: Yes, if you download from python.org, you need to use the 32-bit-only installer

Comment: Here's some information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384021/idle-and-idle-3-crash-on-opening-mac-osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 3.x is better for macs. try downloading it [here](http://python.org/download/releases/3.1.5/) and using IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

On mac idle crashes when you import something big from outside, when you copy-paste  something and when you click on preferences.
Copy-paste error message:

IDLE quit unexpectedly

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
```

All the version of python crashes on mac. So far, i didn't see any solution to this problem.
I strongly recommend you to use iep. It has all the version of python and you don't need to save the file to run it.

Here is [a link](http://code.google.com/p/iep/downloads/list) to iep editor

Comment: I have the same exact problem with any Cmd+key combination (or its command from the menu selection).

Any solutions. I'm using Python 3.3.2

Carlos